# Kudu on IIS, orphaned site

Tags: iis, kudu

I have Kudu running nicely on IIS, unfortunately, I have one small problem. There is currently an orphan site which Kudu won't let me manage. I can find no trace of the site on the server and when I try and go into it or delete it from the dashboard I get:

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

I can't seem to work out where Kudu is storing the details of applications that it knows about so that I can go in and edit them. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea how my orphaned site got on there but deleting all sites has fixed the issue.